# how to create a table with thead inside the getJSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
   header {
           background-color:black;
           color:white;
           text-align:center;
           padding:5px;   
  }
   nav {
       line-height:30px;
       background-color:#eeeeee;
       height:300px;
       width:400px;
       float:left;
       padding:10px;       
  }
   section {
            width:600px;
            float:right;
            padding:10px;    
  }

 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Generate your own query</h1>
  </header>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">          </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var i=0;

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#driver").click(function(event){
      $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
          $('#stage').empty();
          $('#stage').append('<p class="selected first"> Queries: ' + jd.queries_status+ '</p>');
          var $tthead=$("#usertable thead");
          //$tthead.html ="";
          /* var theaddata="";
           theaddata += "<tr>";
           theaddata +=  "<th>" + query_id + "</th>";
           theaddata +=  "<th>" + query_status + "</th>";
           theaddata +=  "<th>" + query_result_number + "</th>";
           theaddata +=  "<th>" + query_results + "</th>";
           theaddata += "<th>" +action + "</th>";
           theaddata += "</tr>";
           $tthead.append(theaddata);*/

           var $tbody = $("#usertable tbody");
           $tbody.html(""); 
            var tabledata = "";
                for(i = 0; i < jd.list_of_queries.length; i++ ){
                      tabledata = "";
                      tabledata += "<tr>";
                      tabledata += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[i].query_id + "</td>";
                      tabledata += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[i].query_status + "</td>";
                      tabledata += "<td>" +jd.list_of_queries[i].query_results_number + "</td>";
                      tabledata += "<td>" +jd.list_of_queries[i].query_results + "</td>";
                      tabledata += "<td>" + '<input type="button" value="details" onclick= "display(this)" name=" '+jd.list_of_queries[i].query_id+' " />' + "</td>";
                      tabledata += "</tr>";
                      $tbody.append(tabledata); 

                                   }
                                });
                            }); 
                     });

     function display(value) {
            $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
            var $tdetail = $("#detail tbody");
            $tdetail.html("");
            var tabledetail = "";
             for(i = 0; i < jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks.length; i++ ){
                tabledetail = "";
                tabledetail += "<tr>";
                tabledetail += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].task_id + "</td>";
                tabledetail += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].task_status + "</td>"; 
                tabledetail+= "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].task_operation + "</td>";
                tabledetail += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].number_of_hits + "</td>";
                tabledetail += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].finished_hits + "</td>";
                tabledetail += "<td>" + jd.list_of_queries[value.name-1].list_of_tasks[i].task_result_number + "</td>";
                tabledetail +="</tr>";
                $tdetail.append(tabledetail); 
              }
            });
       }
  </script>
  </head>

 <section>
    <div id="stage1" >
      Please enter your query <input type="text" name="query" size="50">
  </div>
  <div id="stage">
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="driver" value="submit query" formaction="http://localhost/queryexample.html"/>
  <br />
  <br />
    <table id="usertable" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing=0>
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>query id</th>
         <th>query status</th>
         <th>query result_number</th>
         <th>query results</th>
         <th>action</th>
       </tr> 
      </thead>
      <tbody> </tbody>
   </table>
  <br />

  <form>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="go back"formaction="http://localhost/queryexample.html"  >
  </form>
</section>

<nav>
   <table id="detail" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing=0>
     <tbody> </tbody>
   </table>
   <br />
</nav>
```

currently, I create the table at the initial page, with the thead of the table. Is it possible to make the thead and the tbody of the table inside the getJSON function? thanks in advance.The comment code is what I tried before, but it does not work, hope somebody could revise.

Comment: Please change title from "thread" to "thead"

Comment: i made a fiddle for your problem and had to change some brackets to get no more javascript errors, but of course without your json not being accessible via web, the code won't run fully. but a good start for other motivated helpers: http://jsfiddle.net/n2v290gv/

Comment: the current code could run, but the thead is on the initial page, I did not see the difference between your code and mine.....

Comment: Where are variables query_id, query_status, etc. defined?